# Select data attribute from one div, add class to another div which has same data attribute value

Tags: jquery

### I have 2 divs which have the same data attribute like so:

```js
$("#devMap div").click(function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('data-name');

    alert(data); //this is getting the correct data-name value

    if($('#accordian .blocks').data('name')===data){    
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); // i want this to add the class active to the #accordian .blocks which has the data-name equal to the #devMap div data-name value
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="devMap">
        <div class="toggleAccordian" data-name="block1"></div>
        <div class="toggleAccordian" data-name="block2"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="accordian">
        <div class="blocks" data-name="block1"></div>
        <div class="blocks" data-name="block2"></div>
    </div>
```

I want that when a user clicks `on #devMap .toggleAccordian` it toggles a class on the same data-name attribute under `#accordian`, I tried this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get all `.block` elements having attribute data-name equal to current data name:

```
$('#accordian .blocks[data-name="'+data+'"]').toggleClass('active');
```